How to obtain Secure Boot and TPM 2.0 on my Motherboard: SABERTOOTH X58 Rev 1.xx Serial Number: B2M0AC164797 w/BIOS AMI 0802?
11/25/2024: I am satisfied. Windows 10 is functioning and updates normally. Secure boot TPM 2.0 and UEFI capabilities are unobtainable with the current Legacy BIOS. Question answered. Case closed.

11/22/2024: Thank you Ramhound, for your advice, education, and proofreading. Windows 10 problems solved:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-troubleshooters-1c8cf7ce-0388-4ed3-985d-a305432ae702
And:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d



I updated my ancient NVIDIA GeForce 210 Graphics card to the latest available update. The display on both monitors have noticeably improved. I did not see mention of WDDM drivers from NVIDIA.
Not mentioned in my initial question, recently Windows 10 cannot update features and security. MS Techs are yet to find a solution. I was concerned my old BIOS may have contributed to this problem but the available ASUS BIOS updates do not appear to address the issue.
I regularly clone my OS SSD and Data WD HDs. My Legacy BIOS tags each drive with MBR. I do not know if they would open or function on a UEFI BIOS motherboard.
Although Microsoft will soon cease updating Windows 10 features, I understand Microsoft will offer Windows 10 users some security updates at a nominal annual cost.
I must accept what I can do without learning new OS software and/or buy some new hardware, something to avoid. I spend my time researching history and genealogy and writing stories. I thought getting Secure Boot would keep my status quo.

I wish to do something with the BIOS to obtain Secure Boot, TPM 2.0 and UEFI capabilities.
Below are the specs of my 13-year-old PC.
Device Name:    MY-2011-DESKTOP
Motherboard:    SABERTOOTH X58 Rev 1.xx 
Serial Number: B2M0AC164797
1.  BIOS:   American Megatrends Inc. 0802 12/21/2010 Updates available (not installed) are:
    BIOS Version 0902 (2011/01/08) [Improve USB compatibility]
    BIOS Version 1006 (2011/04/21) [Update Intel Raid Option ROM & Fix USB3.0 Overcurrent check]
    BIOS Version 1201 (2011/07/02) [Improve System stability & support new CPUs.]
    BIOS Version 1304 (2011/09/26) [Improve stability on Marvell controller]
    BIOS Version 1402 (2012/08/29) [Improve VT-d compatibility issue]
Processor:  Intel® Core™ i7 CPU 950 @ 3.07GHz  3068  Mhz, 4 Core, 8 Logical Processor(s)
Installed RAM:  24.0 GB   System type:  64-bit operating system, x64-based processor


Based on the fact information your system has BIOS not UEFI which means Secure Boot cannot be enabled. It cannot be enabled because it does not support Secure Boot. There is nothing you can do with that hardware

There is one thing you can do with that hardware in order to get a few more years out of it: Install a beginner friendly light Linux distro.

@ChanganAuto, with 24 GB RAM and 3 GHz I7, any version of Linux should be fine. That said, one would have to physically modify the motherboard (i.e., cutting traces, adding new wiring, all to support the new TPM chip needed). Not practical to add TP, but Linux doesn't need it..

@DrMoishePippik Sure, but... It's 2010 hardware and I assumed it has a GPU of similar vintage and an HDD. Therefore, modern distros running Gnome aren't recommended, regardless of the amount of RAM. Arguably the best compromise between "modernity" and performance in old hardware is DeepinOS (DDE uses less graphical resources than Gnome; maybe a little more than XFCE).

What does "Windows 10 restored w/windows troubleshooters" mean?, if you solve the problem, wonderful.  We just need to know. All display drivers on Windows are WDDM drivers

I’m voting to close this question because it appears the author has resolved their problem according to their last edit.  The author’s system still doesn’t appear to support Secure Boot.
